# Image alignment issue after a call interruption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

In my application the images alignment goes wrong after a call interruption. Do any one have some idea about this ? Do I want to code in  **applicationWillResignActive:**  for re-align my images in the application. Please tell the reason for it if you know.

Comment: Assuming this has your image(s) being positioned in code, please post the relevant methods.

Comment: I have positioned the images in xib file only.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by by their alignment going 'wrong', perhaps with a before/after screenshot? As far as I know, the images shouldn't change size or position unless you're modifying their frame property somewhere.

Comment: Its an anlog clock , when i end the call the clock's hand move from center part to the right side of the clock circle.

Answer (score 0):

In the nib, look at your images in the "size" view, and take a close look at your struts and springs. You should probably have the top and left strut set, but NO springs. If you have springs set, then the image may get squished when the call comes in, the stretched back when the call is over.